# Merge overlaping objects with interval properties in array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I found similar questions but approved answers do not work for my problem.

I have an input: array of range objects each containing:

- `start`: Integer, start of range,
- `end`: Integer, end of the range.

Output should be:

An array of non-overlapping range objects covering the same range(s) as input ordered from smallest start to largest start. Two ranges are not overlapping if:

- `range1.start <= range2.start`, and
- `range1.end >= range2.start`

**Input:**

```
[
  { start: 8, end: 10 },
  { start: 5, end: 7  },
  { start: 9, end: 12 },
  { start: 2, end: 6  },
]
```

**output:**

```
 [
   { start: 2, end: 7  },
   { start: 8, end: 12 }
 ]
```

As I mentioned, I tried applying solutions on the web for Merging overlapping intervals but they do not do the job.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could sort the array by `start` and `end` and iterate the sorted array with a check for the ranges if they overlap.

```js
var data = [{ start: 8, end: 10 }, { start: 5, end: 7 }, { start: 9, end: 12 }, { start: 2, end: 6 }],
    result = data
        .sort(function (a, b) { return a.start - b.start || a.end - b.end; })
        .reduce(function (r, a) {
            var last = r[r.length - 1] || [];
            if (last.start <= a.start && a.start <= last.end) {
                if (last.end < a.end) {
                    last.end = a.end;
                }
                return r;
            }
            return r.concat(a);
        }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ranges = [
  { start: 8, end: 10 },
  { start: 5, end: 7  },
  { start: 9, end: 12 },
  { start: 2, end: 6  }
];


function merge(ranges) {
  // first, sort the ranges
  ranges.sort((a, b) => a.start - b.start);
  
  // take two ranges, and merges them together
  var mergeFn = (a, b) => ({start: Math.min(a.start, b.start), end: Math.max(a.end, b.end)});
  
  // check if two ranges overlap
  var overlapFn = (a, b) => (b.start <= a.end);
  
  // make current the first item of the array (start the array from 1 to not check the first item against itself)
  var current = ranges[0];
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 1; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    if(overlapFn(current, ranges[i])) // if the current range overlapping with this range
       current = mergeFn(current, ranges[i]); // merge them into the current range
    else { // if not
      result.push(current); // add the current accumulated range as result
      current = ranges[i]; // start accumulating another one from this range
    }
  }
  result.push(current); // add the last result

  return result;
}

console.log(merge(ranges));
```

Comment: Thank you, Ibrahim. For some reason the code you provided did not work for me (a and b could not be recognized by validator on the page I am working on) but I see that here your code works. I used Nina's code and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! Maybe your browser doesn't support **Arrow Functions** (assuming that you code is for browser use).